# The Dynamic Constant Matrix for the Green Function in the Thermal Conductance Calculation

Tags: density-functional-theory, electronic-transport, transport, greens-functions, lattice-thermal-conductivity

When computing the thermal transmission coefficient, the green function needs to be computed first; for example, $G^{R}_{scattering\:region}=\left[\left(\omega+i0^{+}\right)^{2}I-D\right]^{-1}$, where $D$ is named the dynamic constant matrix.

I compare it with the retarded green function for the scattering region in the charge conductance. I found that this dynamic constant matrix is just the off-diagonal matrix in the Hamiltonian, which is the interaction matrix between the lead and the central scattering region. Is my understanding correct?

Would anyone please give me some explanation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @nickpapior I know you are the expert in the non-equilibirum green function (NEGF) method. Would you please have a look at my posted question and give me some explanations? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For phonon transport the Green function formalism is largely equivalent as for electrons.

The primary change is that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf H &\to \mathbf D
\\
\mathbf S &\to \mathbf I
\\
\epsilon &\to \epsilon^2
\end{aligned}
$$
In practice the overlap matrix could be a mass-matrix so $\mathbf D$ becomes mass-independent. But that is a minor detail.

All of the Green function is then the same (if I haven't forgotten anything).
The self-energies are calculated as needed by the same transformations as shown above, and the full device Green function can be constructed equivalently.

What is typically a bit harder for phononic systems is that the range of interaction is typically much longer. Hence the electrodes, and device systems should equally be larger to still obey the decoupling of the electrodes from each other (no left $\to$ right coupling).

So $\mathbf D$ is still containing the elements that couple it to the electrodes, and the electrodes self-energies should still be inserted in the full device Green function:
$$
G(\epsilon) = \big[(\epsilon^2 + i\eta ^2)\mathbf I - \mathbf D - \sum_i \boldsymbol\Sigma_i  \big]^{-1}
$$
where $\boldsymbol\Sigma_i$ is the self-energy of the $i$'th (phononic) electrode. Note how I prefer to decouple the $\epsilon$ and $\eta$. The $\eta$ is a numerical trick to move the Green function away from the real-axis. Hence, it makes no sense to add the $2i\epsilon\eta$ to the complex part as that would create an *energy dependent shift into the complex plane*. You'll quite often see $(\epsilon + i\eta)^2$ in litterature (as you have written), but IMHO it is complicating matters.
The reason for choosing $\eta^2$ is that the energy units of the phonon Green function is $1/[E]^2$ and hence the $\eta$ value should equally be in that unit. And since energies/couplings in dynamical matrices are typically much smaller (numerically) than Hamiltonian elements one also requires a much smaller $\eta$ value. Consider $\eta = 10^{-2}$ which would result in an imaginary part of $0.0001$.
This is just to mention that the typical choices of $\eta$ values for electronic systems can also be used in phononic systems, perhaps even smaller values. But that is again system dependent and requires care from the user.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation with so many details. Your answer is quite helpful to me. I am thinking about another question. If there are three or more leads, connecting the central scattering region. How to compute the thermal transmission coefficient in each lead. Is there any reference paper discussing this issue? Thank you again.

Comment: @Kieran since you wrote that comment on 16 Feb, you might have noticed that it's better to ask questions like that one in posts rather than in comments.

Comment: @I have no free time anymore Thank you for your suggestions. I will post a new question.